# Get the part of an image where the user clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, click, dom-events

Is it possible to find where the user clicked on the image?

I have an image - and onto the image the user can click. And I am trying to find a way, how to get the place, when the user clicked.

Comment: Are you looking for [imagemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On image click you can find the coordinates where the user clicked using the event object.

```
$("imageSelector").click(function(e){
  var pos = $(this).position();
  //The following are the x/y coordinates of the mouse click relative to image.
  var x = e.pageX - pos.left;
  var y = e.pageY - pos.top;
});
```

Comment: This method will be off by the thicknesses of the image's: border, padding and margin.

Comment: I dont think we can give padding to image tag. Yes, if it has any margin or border then we need to consider it as well. But rarely we give border or margin to image tags.

Comment: Of course it can have padding; See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VkezC/4/).  And images have margin or padding quite frequently.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. But now I am solving just one problem - I am loading some image and I have the directions - and I would like after loading the image add this directions to an image, something like: `<?php if isset($image) { //add the "small image" to the bigger } ?>` - but I am not sure, how to do. Should I after php condition call some javascript function or how would be possible to solve it? Thank you one more time.

Answer (score 2):

Don't be fooled by methods that fail to take margin, padding, and border into account!

This is the code you need. :

```
$("#myImage").click ( function (evt) {

    var jThis               = $(this);
    var offsetFromParent    = jThis.position ();
    var topThickness        = (jThis.outerHeight(true) - jThis.height() ) / 2;
    var leftThickness       = (jThis.outerWidth (true) - jThis.width () ) / 2;

    //--- (x,y) coordinates of the mouse click relative to the image.
    var x                   = evt.pageX - offsetFromParent.left - leftThickness;
    var y                   = evt.pageY - offsetFromParent.top  - topThickness;
} );
```

[**See it in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/VkezC/4/)

Comment: Is there an updated version to this using Vanilla JS? Or React?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the mouse position easily, and then you can add something to that point relative to the image.

Here's an example of mouse position: [jquery.com](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position)